# Save each line of echo output as variable BASH

Tags: bash, for-loop, echo

I'm working to create a simple script where I can save each line as a variable for later use. However it didn't go well. Can anybody help me please.

```
read -p  "Enter the number of user and press [ENTER]:" num
   for ((i=1; i<=$num; i++)); do
           var$i="|-> Line $i"
           echo "var$i"

   done
```

I'm trying to obtain the output that looks like this

```
|-> Line 1
|-> Line 2
|-> Line 3
|-> Line 4
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not *too* far off. Just use an array:

```
read -p  "Enter the number of user and press [ENTER]:" num
for ((i=0; i<$num; i++)); do
    var[$i]="|-> Line $((i+1))"
    echo "${var[i]}"
done

for line in "${var[@]}"
do
    echo "Saved line: $line"
done
```

where the latter gives an example how to retrieve it later.  Also, arrays are zero-indexed and I've adjusted it accordingly.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks a lot ! So what you have done is put them into an array ?

Comment: Yeah,your answer do it better.

Comment: Yes, this puts them in an array. It also relies on the fact that an undefined variable (when used as an array) acts identically to an empty array. But you could also say `var=()` above to be more explicit and to clear anything that might have previously been defined in `var`.

Answer (score 0):

Can this meet your requirement?

```
read -p  "Enter the number of user and press [ENTER]:" num
   for ((i=1; i<=$num; i++)); do
       var_j="|-> Line $i"
       echo $var_j

   done
```